# Expected value of ratio of two function of the same random variable

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a r.v. with absolutely continuous distribution and continuous strictly positive density $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ and let $g$ a further given continuous density function.

Set
$$
Y = \frac{g(X)}{f(X)}.
$$
What can we say about the $\mathbb{E}Y$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This representation is the principle behind [importance sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Importance_sampling).

If $X\sim f(x)$, then [since $Y$ is a transform of $X$, by the law of the unconscious statistician]
$$^Y[Y]=^X[\frac{g(X)}{f(X)}=∫\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}f(x)\text{d}x$$
which simplifies into
$$∫_{\text{supp}(f)}g(x)\,\frac{f(x)}{f(x)}\text{d}x=∫_{\text{supp}(f)}g(x)\,\text{d}x$$
where $\text{supp}(f)$ denotes the support of $f$, that is the closure of the collection of points $x$ when $f(x)>0$. In the event when $\text{supp}(g)\subset\text{supp}(f)$ the integral is equal to one.